# Magento: How to set session website to admin user?

Tags: php, magento-1.4, magento

i have 3 websites running over one Magento installation and 3 admin users for each store.

- store123.com (admin123)
- store456.com (admin456)
- store789.com (admin798)

i have created a custom module to set the user admin of website, but how to set the default website of user when he authenticate into Magento Admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AdminGws module from Magento Enterprise Edition. Unfortunately, this modules was not disponible on Magento Connect and I don't find another solution yet.

Comment: Dammit! i wish build my own custom module.

Comment: I guess you have to overwrite a lot of models to make it work. It seems very complicated, but if you customer is paying, why not? You should try contact Magento Sales and try buy just that module.